# Crystal Reports won't log into MySQL-Database in Windows 10 64 Bit System from installed Visual .net-project

Tags: c#, sql-server, authentication, crystal-reports, windows-10

**The Problem:**

We have a software-project coded in C#/.Net with report functions built on Crystal Reports. This project worked for years with this functions until someday it came to a strange error. If the project was installed on a 64-Bit Windows System Crystal Reports won't log in into the Report-Viewer. This means, before the report was shown to the user, there will be a window, in which you have to insert your credentials of your Database. Sadly after giving the credentials, no login will be performed, instead there will be a message telling the user that the login failed. And after that the login box returns. It doesn't matter, what you insert into the password or user field, there won't be a login.

[Login Screen Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15m8i.png)

[Login Issue Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnF8R.png)

Well, **this error could be solved** by installing the 32-Bit version of the sql-native Client from 2005 or 2008 instead of the 64-Bit version. But now Windows 10 64 Bit doesn't allow to install a 32-Bit version of this native sql clients. Therefore the old fix doesn't work anymore and the problem returned.

This question is discussing the same problem (like many other threads), without a solution.

[Stackoverflow Question asking kind of the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34718542/database-login-dialog-popup-when-a-crystal-report-project-is-x64)

We have two computers with windows 10 64 bit on which the problem occurs. On one of them, the login window has no database selected (visible in the database-field). On the other computer, this field is correctly filled with the database. We found no difference in the behavior of both issues, except from the empty field. We tested, if the database wasn't correctly given to Crystal Report. It was, but the field still remained empty on one of the computers. This issue is also discussed on the internet without a solution (at least I couldn't find some). As an example, in the following link the problem with the empty Database-field is discussed.

[Example with a question about the empty database field.](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24124955/Crystal-Reports-NET-logon-screen-promt-on-client-machine-database-field-empty.html)

The "best" solution in the thread above is "There is no solution to this problem. Regards [...]", which is not a good solution.

There is another observation. The problem doesn't occur, if the windows 10 System is an upgrade from a lower system, on which the 32-bit version of the Sql-Native-Clients was installed. Therefore, Crystal Report can run indeed on windows 10 64 bit, if the correct environment could be installed. But we can't install the needed clients on the freshly installed 64-bit systems.

**What was done until this question:**

Cause the Code does work on every other system, except from a freshly installed Windows 10 64-bit one, we haven't looked into the Code deeply for the fixing. Instead we concentrated firstly on internet research and secondly on trying to get the sql native clients 32-bit on the new systems (or at least the needed dlls). Therefore we tested:

**Registry Solution**
Cause a research-founding, we tried to add the registry entries under "SAP BusinessObjects" into the "WOW6432Node", if it wasn't there. This didn't fix anything at all.

**DLL Copies**
We tried to determine the dll-files installed by the sql-native Clients 32-bit and manually copy them into the folders. But all the systems already had them.

We unzipped the msi for the native clients and tested for the dlls in the msi directly. Also we searched for the files, that will be copied into the System32 folder directly and found them.

[(German) Microsoft site with information about dlls](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms131321(v=sql.120).aspx)

"Die SQL Server Native Client-Dateien (sqlncli11.dll, sqlnclir11.rll und s11ch_sqlncli.chm) werden in folgendem Verzeichnis installiert:

%SYSTEMROOT%\system32"

Meaning: The SQL Server Native Client-files (sqlncli11.dll, sqlnclir11.rll and s11ch_sqlncli.chm) will be installed in the following folder:

%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\

So we checked for this files and also for the sqlncli...dll files with lower version (10). They were in the system folders.

Cause the dlls may not be compiled in the GAC folder, this may not be the solution at all (cause we can't write them into the folder without installing the 32-bit versions).

**Installing all the available sql-native clients for 64 bit**
Hoping, that one of the versions had the needed files in them, we installed all the version for the 64-bit version, but without success.

**Clearing the Connection for Crystal Report in Code**
Following a solution from the internet, we tried to clear the DataSourceConnections before setting the new one. Just for testing purpose, if this may help (which it didn't).

[Some Solutions for the Problem, that didn't work for us](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/748565/My-Crystal-reports-asks-for-database-login-while-l)

**Debugging and Research**
As said in the text above, we tested the Information in Code and found no problem with the connections. We could connect with the same information in the database from every other tool of the program. The issue only occurs with Crystal Report. Also researching the issue showed only "open" questions without answers, or without answers that worked for us.

**The Question**

What to do, to get into the CrystalReport-Viewer without the login-window failing to login?

As solutions there may be two ways to fix this. One within the code, and one with the needed files from the sql native clients, or other environmental changes.

Both solutions are welcome. Of course we will further search for solutions ourself, but in the moment, we are a little clueless (which explains this question).

So any help is welcome.

And at last a little Code:

```
repdoc.FileName = _pfad;

if ([...]Configuration.ServerType == [...].DB.Utils.ServerTypeMSSQL)
{
    if (repdoc.DataSourceConnections.Count > 0)
               repdoc.DataSourceConnections[0].SetConnection([...]Configuration.Server, [...]Configuration.Database, DatenbankAdministration.DefaultUser, DatenbankAdministration.DefaultPassword);

    repdoc.SetDatabaseLogon([...]Configuration.User, [...]Configuration.Password, [...]Configuration.Server, [...]Configuration.Database);
}

repdoc.Load(_pfad);
```

In this code example, we set the filepath towards the report and the connection towards the database. Everything is correctly filled on the systems with issues. But if there are some configurations to be done, feel free to comment them.

If you are interested to look into the issues, but need some further information, that we can provide, I will happily provide them.

Comment: We have similar issue and finally found that one machine had Office 2003 (worked) and other had Office (2007) and didn't work.  Oledb uses Jet Engine and the Jet may be different.  Jet is the database that is used by Excel and Access.  We had a macro and MSDN recommends for 32 bit to use a LONG and for 64 bit use a Long PTR.  Well the MSDN recommendation does not work.

Comment: First, I'm sorry for answering this late.

I'm thankfulll for your kind input and will look into this, if it will help us.